# How to ignore .gitignore file?

Tags: git

I created a .gitignore to ignore an untracked file called tola.txt, now when i do git status  now tola.txt is gone but .gitignore is coming under untracked files. I have temp moved an entry .gitignore inside .gitignore file, but that's just a hack I believe, how can i get rid of this .gitignore mess?

```
root>$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   tola.txt
root>$ vim .gitignore
```

added tola.txt in .gitignore, but now .gitignore has become the untracked

```
root>$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
```

Comment: If you don't add `.gitignore`, no one else will know that `tola.txt` should be ignored and they'll accidentally commit it. `.gitignore` should be tracked.

Answer (score 7):

IF you want everyone who uses the repo ( clones ) to have the file ignored, you add the `.gitignore` to your repo ( as in `git add .gitignore` followed by a `git commit` )

If you don't want others to see it or you are just trying things out and don't want to see the .gitignore, you can the patterns  you want to ignore to the `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` file. That is, you can add the `tola.txt` line to `.git/info/exclude` file.

Comment: +1. Git's local exclude-file is the easiest way forward. Another option is to add .gitignore to itself (or to .git/info/exclude)..

Comment: @BarendGarvelink - Yeah, but I don't like adding `.gitignore` to itself as that defeats the *intent*

Comment: I agree with you. It'll also be surprising if someone else adds a .gitignore file at some point in the future. `.git/info/exclude` is the proper way for local ignores.

Comment: I have to create an empty file "exclude"? because I do not have initial one in this directory